# Передача параметра через переменную среды для дочернего процесса

Tags: c++, winapi

Есть родительский процесс, через него открываю дочерний процесс.

Нужно через переменную среды передать параметр UserProfile в дочерний процесс.

Когда пишу следующий код - выдает ошибку доступа.

```
STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    SetEnvironmentVariable(L"UserProfile", L"%UserProfile%");
    GetEnvironmentVariable(L"UserProfile", buffer1, 100);
    wstring star1(buffer1);
    wstring str12 = L"C:\\ConsoleApplication1\\Debug\\ConsoleApplication1.exe";
    TCHAR szCmdline1[] = TEXT("C:\\ConsoleApplication1\\Debug\\ConsoleApplication1.exe");
    CreateProcess(NULL, szCmdline1, NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, L"C:\\ConsoleApplication1", &si, &pi);
```

В котором ConsoleApplication1.exe - дочерний процесс.

Answer (score 3):

А попроще не хотите? У меня вполне работает такое, например:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    const char* user = getenv("UserProfile");
    cout << "UserProfile = " << user << endl;
    if (strcmp(user,"tester") != 0)
    {
        const char * env[] = {"UserProfile=tester", nullptr };
        _spawnle(_P_WAIT,argv[0],argv[0],nullptr,env);
    }
}
```

(чтоб не преумножать сущности сверх необходимости, процесс вызывает сам себя).

Comment: этот код в родительском процессе или в дочернем?

Comment: Я же написал - *процесс вызывает сам себя*. Он и родительский (когда `strcmp(user,"tester") != 0`), и дочерний.